# sort Posts by custom user filed

Tags: custom-taxonomy, custom-field, loop, sort, user-registration

So I'm trying to sort the posts by custom user filed,
I'll explain...

So I have added users filed to the registration page, 
The fields are checkboxes, they allow the user to choose what topic he is interested in.

Example:

> What topics are you interested in?
>
> Design
>
> Science
>
> Geography
>
> Computer
>
> Poetry

I want that after the user registered and chose the option from the registration check boxes,
Once he login to his account,  he will see the posts from the topics he is interested in on top.

Do you know what would be the best way to acheive this?

Answer (score 0):

So, if you want to display only posts on your homepage, which interests the logged in user, you can use [the pre_get_posts-Action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts):

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wp123234_user_specific_loop' );
function wp123234_user_specific_loop( $query ){
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() ) //Just return, if the user is not logged in.
        return;

    if( ! $query->is_main_query() ) //If its not the main query return
        return;

    if( !$query->is_home() ) //If its not the "home"-query return
        return;

    $interests = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'interests', true );
    if( empty( $interests ) ) //If the user has no interests return
        return;

    /*Now, we want to display the specific posts.*/

    //Assuming, the $interests-Array contains category-IDs
    //$query->set( 'category__in', $interests );

    //Assuming, the $interests-Array contains custom fields of posts
    $query->set( 'meta_query', array( array(
            'key'     => 'interests',
            'value'   => $interests,
            'compare' => 'IN',
        ) ) );

    //Assuming, you want to ignore sticky posts, since they might show up, although the
    //user is not interested in
    $query->set( 'ignore_sticky_posts', true );
}
```

Comment: `pre_get_posts` is an action, not a filter.